# How to filter data into two new data frames

Tags: r, filtering

Let's say I have one data frame named `MLTXZP` that looks like this:

```
1   0.00038 0.75053 0.50    35  6000    0.75346
2   0.00038 0.75053 0.50    35  6050    0.72079
3   0.00038 0.75053 0.50    35  6100    0.69229
4   0.00038 0.75053 0.50    35  6150    0.66689
5   0.00038 0.75053 0.50    35  6200    0.64382
...
7247    0.00061 0.74996 0.80    105 6800    0.61635
```

and another data frame named `populations` that looks like this. Note that the second column is either `0` or `1`.

```
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
...
7247 1
```

Notice how the first column of both files are the same? I want to create two new data frames that are subsets of `MLTXZP`. I want one data frame to be MLTXZP but only the rows which have the `0` tag from the second file. I want the other data frame to be MLTXZP but only the rows which have the `1` tag from the second file. Is there a great way to do this?

EDIT: Column names for `MLTXZP`
"model ID", "Z", "X", "M", "L", "T", "non-linear period"

Column names for `populations` (I may rename this data frame`)
"model ID", "population num"

Comment: Can you provide column names?

Comment: `result = split(MLTXZP, populations[2])` will give a `list` with the split data frames in it. You can reference them with `result[["0"]]` and `result[["1"]]` (though it is probably safer to rename them with non-numeric names).

Comment: @cmirian Thomas See edit for column names that I gave them.